# Send $_POST[] and $_FILES[] in same Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on an image upload post part of my site and I am struggeling to be able to upload the image with the date. I am sending the date via `$_POST` and the files for the images in `$_FILES`.

Here is my code (Javascript):

```
(function post_image_content() {
var input = document.getElementById("images"), 
    formdata = false;

function showUploadedItem (source) {
    var list = document.getElementById("image-list"),
        li   = document.createElement("li"),
        img  = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = source;
    li.appendChild(img);
    list.appendChild(li);
}   

if (window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData();
    document.getElementById("btn").style.display = "none";
}


input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
    var data = '';
    date = document.getElementById('image_date').value;
    if(date == ''){
        alert('Please select a date!');
        return 0;
    } else {
        data = 'date='+date;
    }

    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Uploading . . ."
    var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;

    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
        file = this.files[i];

        if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
            if ( window.FileReader ) {
                reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                    showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
            if (formdata) {
                formdata.append("images[]", file);
            }
        }   
    }

    if (formdata) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "submit_image.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata + ' ' + data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (res) {
                $('#images').show();
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
                hideImageUpload(); 
            }
        });
    }
}, false);
}());

function hideImageUpload(){
$('#image_upload_form').hide(250);
//$('#response').hide(250);
$('#image-list').hide(250);
}
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
$user = new User();
$errors = $_FILES["images"]["error"];
$date = $_POST['date'];

$date = explode("/", $date);
$newdate = $date[2] + '-' + $date[0] + '-' + $date[1];

foreach ($errors as $key => $error) {
if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $name = $_FILES["images"]["name"][$key];
    //$ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $name = explode("_", $name);
    $imagename='';
    foreach($name as $letter){
        $imagename .= $letter;
    }

    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], "images/uploads/" . $user->data()->id . '_' . $imagename);

    $user->create('photos', array(
        'osid' => $user->data()->id,
        'user' => $user->data()->username,
        'gallery' => 'Uploads',
        'filename' => "images/uploads/" . $user->data()->id . '_' . $imagename,
        'date' => $newdate
    ));
}
}


echo "<h2>Successfully Uploaded Images</h2>";
```

I am new to web development, and I am using PDO to enter into database.

Answer (score 0):

Wait... `data: formdata + ' ' + data,` It is slightly confusing. You add `FormData` object and string containing url-encoded data.

Append date value to your `formdata` object: `formdata.append('date', date)`. After this, send AJAX query with `data: formdata,` only.

But there may be more errors.

For debugging, use *Chrome developer tools*. You can use `debugger` and `console.log(something)` for breakpoint and printing your vars. Also, you always can use step-by-step debugging.

Comment: If you get this without any other information, you almost certainly have error in PHP code. But PHP doesn't print it due to disabled error reporting. When developing, always turn on verbose error reporting, including notices and warnings.

First, debug your JS code. You can find out whether your data is sent using network tab in _Chrome Developer Tools_ or some third-party program like _MS Network Monitor_. Look at enctype attribute and learn difference between _urlencoded_ and _multipart-form-data_.

Comment: Handling file uploads in PHP is easier, in my opinion.

Though, you always can use plain forms without JS for debugging you PHP code. For PHP it doesn't matter whether you post data via AJAX or normal form.

PDO is great. Use it instead of mysql_* functions.